# Simplifying fractions - Ending up with wrong sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I've been trying to simplify this
$$
1-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2) (n+3)}
$$
to get it to that
$$
1-\frac{(n+3)-1}{(n+2)(n+3)}
$$
but I always end up with this
$$
1-\frac{(n+3)+1}{(n+2)(n+3)}
$$
Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?
Wolfram Alpha gets it to correct form but it doesn't show me the steps (even in pro version)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everywhere there is a minus sign, replace it with plus a negative.

So with your original expression, try instead simplifying
$$
1+\frac{-1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2) (n+3)}
$$
and you should be much less prone to error.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You just have the problem that while $$x-y+z = x-(y-z)$$

you are instead writing:$$x-y+z=x-(y+z)$$

Comment: This is very useful thing to remember! Unbelievable how I missed such a simple property! Wish I could select 2 answers as best.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to see a full simplification:

\begin{align*}
1-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} &= \frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{(n+2)(n+3)} - \frac{(n+3)}{(n+2)(n+3)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} \\
&= \frac{(n+2)(n+3)-(n+3)+1}{(n+2)(n+3)}\\
&= \frac{(n^2+5n+6) -n-2 }{(n+2)(n+3)} \\
&= \frac{n^2+4n+4}{(n+2)(n+3)} \\
&= \frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+2)(n+3)} \\
&= \frac{n+2}{n+3} \\
\end{align*}
Provided $n\neq -2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in-depth answer, gives me a look at a new way of working things like that out. Wish I could select multiple answers as best